# How to run PnPUtil as admin from with C# application?

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd, process, runas

I have a directive to install a printer driver programmatically from C# (WPF) application. User must not be allowed to exit my app and install from Windows. I have managed to get this to work great by manually:

1. Installing driver via `pnputil -i -a file.inf`.
   (This works great in both PowerShell and command prompt if elevated.)
2. Add printer driver via PowerShell.
3. Add printer port via PowerShell.
4. Add printer via PowerShell.

If I add driver to store by manually running #1 my code works great. But I cannot get for whatever reason either ps or cmd to run the same command (successfully) from C#. It comes back with error **Driver not in store**. Here is my code from a sandbox app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;

namespace NetworkPrinterDriver
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
Runspace rs;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new      Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
    dlg.Filter = "Information Files (.inf)|*.inf";
    //dlg.Filter = "Executables (.exe)|*.exe";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;
    }
}

private void btnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    driverInstall(FileNameTextBox.Text);
    AddPrinterDriver(txtDriverName.Text);
    AddPrinterPort(txtPortName.Text, txtHostIP.Text);
    AddPrinter(txtPrinterName.Text, txtDriverName.Text, txtPortName.Text);
}

private void driverInstall(string driverPath)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C pnputil -i -a \"{0}\"", driverPath);

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

}

private void AddPrinterPort(string portName, string printerAddress)
{
    string script = string.Format("Add-printerport -Name \"{0}\" -PrinterHostAddress \"{1}\"", portName, printerAddress);
    RunScript(script);
}

private void AddPrinterDriver(string driverName)
{
    string script = string.Format("Add-printerdriver -Name \"{0}\"", driverName);
    RunScript(script);
}

private void AddPrinter(string printerName, string driverName, string portName)
{
    string script = string.Format("Add-printer -Name \"{0}\" -DriverName \"{1}\" -Port \"{2}\"", printerName, driverName, portName);
    RunScript(script);
}

private void RunScript(string script)
{
    rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    rs.Open();

    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddScript(script);
        ps.Runspace = rs;
        ps.Invoke();
        foreach (ErrorRecord err in ps.Streams.Error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }

    // rs.Close();
}

}   // class MainWindow
}   // namespace NetworkPrinterDriver
```

Can someone explain to me what I did wrong?

The cmd prompt does run (Windows asks me to allow it to make changes), but it is not installing the driver. If I copy the same string from the app and paste in to an elevated command prompt it works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the Powershell be elevated too ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

I changed this to use elevated powershell cmd:

```
 var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
 newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
 newProcessInfo.Arguments = string.Format("pnputil -i -a \"{0}\"", driverPath);
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
```

Thanks @Aybe for the hint. Works like a charm. Chased the rabbit.......